# Sed Delete a line if a symbol after a pattern is NOT a number

Tags: sed

I have a text file, containing something like this

```
                ESSID:"228"
                Frequency:5.02 GHz (Channel 4)
                Quality=7/94  Signal level=-89 dBm  Noise level=-99 dBm

                ESSID:"1_156"
                Frequency:5.305 GHz (Channel 61)
                Quality=28/94  Signal level=-68 dBm  Noise level=-98 dBm

                ESSID:""
                Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
                Quality=7/94  Signal level=-89 dBm  Noise level=-98 dBm

                ESSID:""
                Frequency:5.745 GHz (Channel 149)
                Quality=21/94  Signal level=-75 dBm  Noise level=-99 dBm

                ESSID:"Apsnyaimadara"
                Frequency:5.11 GHz (Channel 22)
                Quality=22/94  Signal level=-74 dBm  Noise level=-97 dBm
```

And i want to get rid of all ESSIDs that are not consist of numbers and a "_" sign. Can you please tell how can i delete a line if it contains ESSID:" and next symbol after that pattern won't be a number? =) In fact i'm looking to delete those blocks completely rather than just a line, but i can start from that, any help would be greatly appreciated =)

P.S. using Sed

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Exactly as you did below, again, thanks a lot! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -nE '/ESSID:"[0-9_]+"/,/^$/p' file
```

or with GNU grep:

```
grep -A3 -E 'ESSID:"[0-9_]+"' file
```

Output:

```
                ESSID:"228"
                Frequency:5.02 GHz (Channel 4)
                Quality=7/94  Signal level=-89 dBm  Noise level=-99 dBm

                ESSID:"1_156"
                Frequency:5.305 GHz (Channel 61)
                Quality=28/94  Signal level=-68 dBm  Noise level=-98 dBm
```